# What is wrong with this proof of a number theory competition problem?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, contest-math

Let $a$ and $b$ be positive integers. Suppose $a^n+n| b^n+n$ for any positive integer $n$, prove that $a=b$.

My trial: Clearly $b\geq a$, write $b=a+d$, we must show that $d=0$. Now by assumption and the fact that $a^n \equiv -n \pmod{a^n+n}$, we have
$$0\equiv (a+d)^n+n=a^n+\binom{n}{1}a^{n-1}d+\cdots +\binom{n}{n-1}ad^{n-1}+d^n+n $$
$$\equiv \binom{n}{1}a^{n-1}d+\cdots +\binom{n}{n-1}ad^{n-1}+d^n \pmod{a^n+n}.$$

Hence 
$$\binom{n}{1}a^{n-1}d+\cdots +\binom{n}{n-1}ad^{n-1}+d^n = (a^n+n)q$$
for some positive integer $q$.
Now choose a prime $p> b$, then we have $p|\binom{p}{k}$ for $1\leq k \leq p-1$, hence
$$d^p \equiv a^pq \pmod{p}.$$ By Fermat's Little Theorem, we have $d\equiv aq \pmod{p}$. Thus $d=aq+pk$ for some positive integer $k$. But this equation fails to hold for sufficiently large $p$ unless $d=0$, the result follows.

My question: what's wrong with the above "proof"? Thank you so much!

Comment: In $d=aq+pk$, why $k>0$?

Comment: Edit $d^n \equiv a^pq \pmod{p}$

Comment: If a < b < 2a you can't have d = aq + pk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the last paragraph, how did you derived that $d=aq+pk$ implies that $d=0$?
Observe that the number $q$ is not fixed, hence can change with $p$. But we can deduce from the equation that for sufficiently large prime number $p$, we have $d=aq$ (because $d$ is fixed and numbers in the equation are non-negative).